# prefix assets for production with static path

Tags: ember-cli

for assets such as /assets/image.png, that I call in stylesheets, javascript etc...

I need to prefix or prepend a path to server.

so that /assets/image.png becomes /static/ember/memory/dist/assets/image.png for production.

where it will be served as ie: http://domain.com/static/ember/memory/dist/assets/image.png

i need to pass and use a STATIC_PATH variable when compiled/built for production that will be prefixed, or compile it so that it does it automatically.

I have checked ember-cli docs for assets compilation:

var app = new EmberApp({
   fingerprint: {
      prepend: '/static/ember/memory/dist/'
   }
});

however, this doesn't work as where the assets are being called the path doesn't change in production, unless it actually modified the path where it's called.

for example in styles.css if I call /assets/image.png somewhere, I need to prefix this with STATIC_PATH + /assets/image.png when in production.

the STATIC_PATH will look something like:

/static/ember/memory/dist/

I can add this manually for production in development, but then cannot test in development.

thanks for any response.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `prepend` option in the `ember-cli-build` file, you will have to exclude the assets that don't need the path:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
   fingerprint: {
     exclude: ['excludedAssets/'],
     prepend: '/static/ember/memory/dist/'
   }
});
```

For more information check out [asset compilation](http://www.ember-cli.com/asset-compilation/)