# How do I tell ember-cli to not minify public JS files?

Tags: ember-cli

I am currently including a file ("options.js") in the `public` folder of my app, which is being copied into `dist` appropriately.  The problem is that the "options.js" file includes comments to the user for which items they can edit:

```
window.APP_OVERRIDES = {
 // OPTION_A: 'default' // This option foos the bars
 // OPTION_B: 'wat'     // This option wat?????
};
```

Unfortunately, when I build the app with `--environment=production` this file gets minified like everything else:

```
window.APP_OVERRIDES = {};
```

Is there any way to tell the ember-cli to not minify that one file?

Comment: Take a look at the [exclude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925341/prefix-assets-for-production-with-static-path/31935679#31935679) part.

Comment: @Kitler I can exclude the "options.js" file from fingerprinting.  That works, but can I exclude it from being minified?

Comment: @Kitler Nevermind previous question.  I worked it out.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

After some spelunking into the node modules, I figured out how to tell the minifier to preserve comments. It doesn't specifically tell the ember-cli to ignore "public" files, but it gives better control IMO.

In the `Brocfile.js`, you can add this setting:

```
minifyJS: {
  options: {
    output: {
      comments: /@preserve/
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my `public/options.js` file, I can add a comment in there:

```
/* @preserve 
   Here be some preserved comments
*/
```

Of course, that `comments` option is a regex, so you can add any regex you want there.  If it is found in the comment, it will preserve it.